# Data Droping at transport layer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can we do data droping and filtering at transport layer(TCP).

I want to drop useless packets at Transport layer. To save the bandwidth,energy of nodes and reduce the congestion. So is it possible to drop packets at transport layer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60765/data-droping-at-transport-layer/) by [hannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4685/hannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-15

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-17**:
Please elaborate.

**Comment by [hannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4685/hannan/) on 2013-04-17**:
I want to drop useless packets at Transport layer. To save the bandwidth,energy of nodes and reduce the congestion. So is it possible to drop packets at transport layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to do filtering at the TCP level there are lots of standard tools for doing that such as iptables.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0